# Singleton Design Implementation

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton, global-variables, singleton-methods

As per my previous question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608104/creating-a-global-object-across-classes), I've adapted my Data Controller class over to use a singleton design pattern so that I can use it only once across multiple views. However I do have a couple question I can't seem to find the solution too.

Firstly I'm not exactly sure how to call the class/object in the two views to make it work, and secondly I've made the initialisation method global with + but do I need to do this with each of the methods?

The initialisation of of the class that I want to be able to share across the views, in order to share the data, is

```
static SpeecherDataController *_instance = nil;  // <-- important 

+(SpeecherDataController *)instance
{ 
    // skip everything
    if(_instance) return _instance; 

    // Singleton
    @synchronized([SpeecherDataController class]) 
    {
        if(!_instance)
        {
            _instance = [[self alloc] init];

            //  NSLog(@"Creating global instance!"); <-- You should see this once only in your program
        }

        return _instance;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

The class uses three Mutable Arrays as the main content which need to be both set and read in the two views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your questions correctly, I think the answers are:

1. You can use something like:

   ```
   SpeecherDataController * localReference = [SpeecherDataController instance];
   ```

   and then later:

   ```
   [localReference someMessage:param]; // or ...
   localReference.property = whatever;
   ```
2. No, the methods on your `SpeecherDataController` class do not also need to be made class methods (i.e., they do not need to have the `+` prefix, they can use `-` if you want to access  ivars within them).

Note:  I think you want to replace `[[self alloc] init];` with `[[SpeecherDataController alloc] init];` in your implementation of `instance`.

(Also, note:  I was unable to follow your link to "here" above to see your previous question.  So my apologies if I misunderstood something.)

Comment: Ooops forgot to actually add link. Been added now. But I think you've answer my question.